# How to display post name on new_comment page

Tags: python, django

i would like to know how i can display the name of a post at my comment_new page:

views.py

```
def comment_new(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.published_date = timezone.now()
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully provided a comment for this Post.')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            return render(request, 'app/comment_new.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'app/comment_new.html', {'form': form})

models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Post Title", max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Post Content", max_length=5000)
    tag = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tags/Meta - (sep. by comma)", max_length=50, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

template.html

```
<a>{{ post.title }}</a>
```

the attribute title is given. I have no idea why it does not work.

thanks in Advance

Comment: But you here redirect to `post_detail`, so this view is irrelevant for the rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you want to display the post title when a user is about to add a new comment. I mean, when the request is a GET (display the new message form).

```
def comment_new(request, pk):

    # This line is better here since you'll be working with
    # the post instance no matter the request method is POST or GET.
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        # And here pass post as part of the context to your template.
        return render(request, 'app/comment_new.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})
```